# Convert shape file type from Multipatch to Polygon

Tags: gis, arcgis

I have a shape file of multipatch type and this shape file have a attribute table. I want convert this shp file type to polygon and be retained attribute table. How can i do this task?

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the 3D Analyst Tools --> Conversions --> "Multipatch Footprint" in ArcGIS.

You'll obtain a polygon shapefile with the original multipatch's attribute table.

Answer (score 0):

Tasks for format conversion are covered in the [appropriate documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/multipatch-footprint.htm) and the method chosen will determine the requirements and outputs available.